# Inline CSS with Pandoc

Tags: html, css, scripting, markdown, pandoc

I apologize if a simple way to this programmatically (not by copying/pasting in a browser field and clicking a button to convert) is documented somewhere. In my searches and reading I cannot find it.

I would like to programmatically turn a Markdown and CSS file into what sounds like may be called "inline" CSS.For example:

This Markdown file (`file.md`)

```
# Install
Install instructions

## Update
Update instructions
```

This CSS file (`style.css`)

```
h1 {
    font-size: 100px;
}

h2 {
    color: red;
}
```

Becomes this (`file.html`)

```
<h1 style="font-size: 100px;"><a id="install"></a>Install</h1>
<p>Install instructions</p>
<h2 style="color: red;"><a id="update"><a>Update</h2>
<p>Update instructions</p>
```

I am transforming the Markdown to HTML with [Pandoc](https://pandoc.org/)

```
pandoc -f markdown -t html file.md -o file.html
```

When I use

```
pandoc -f markdown -t html file.md -o file.html --css=style.css --self-contained
```

(or `--standalone`)

It returns

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang xml:lang>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <meta name="generator" content="pandoc" />
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes" />
      <title>file</title>
      <style type="text/css">
          code{white-space: pre-wrap;}
          span.smallcaps{font-variant: small-caps;}
          span.underline{text-decoration: underline;}
          div.column{display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; width: 50%;}
      </style>
      <style type="text/css">h1 {font-size: 100px;}h2 {color: red;}</style>
      <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv-printshiv.min.js"></script>
      <![endif]-->
    </head>
    <body>
      <h1><a id="install"></a>Install</h1>
      <p>Install instructions</p>
      <h2><a id="update"><a>Update</h2>
      <p>Update instructions</p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

As mentioned above this is not my goal. I would like the CSS to be strictly "inline":

```
<h1 style="font-size: 100px;"><a id="install"></a>Install</h1>
```

Is anyone aware of a tool or script already written than can programmatically achieve this? I have searched and come up empty. Ideally I could use Pandoc for this, but I cannot discover a way.

I do not care if the `<head>` and `<style>` blocks of the HTML exist or not. This HTML will be sent via cURL to a content-management system that strips out all HTML elements except the contents inside `<body>` and any "inline" CSS.

Thank you for any thoughts or pointing me in a direction.

Comment: Does your CMS also strip out `<style>` tags within body? The styles don't *have* to be in the header, placing CSS within `<body>` still results in valid HTML.

Comment: you should probably reconfigure your CMS... inline styles are really not good practice...

Comment: @tarleb I did not know this. I will try this method. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a similar scenario and found [`premailer`](https://pypi.org/project/premailer/).
Install with `pip install premailer` and use as `python3 -m premailer -f INPUT.html -o OUT.html`.

Credit: https://qiita.com/kimagure/items/6820e2df2a7604047862

Answer (score 20):

**EDIT 2023/03/24:** The `--self-contained` flag is now depreciated - pandoc will automatically convert it to `--embed-resources --standalone`, which should be used instead.

In short:

- `-s`/`--standalone` "By default, pandoc produces a document fragment". To produce a standalone document (valid HTML file including  and ), use one of those flags.
- `--embed-resource` "Produce a standalone HTML file with no external dependencies..."

---

A better option for most people than `-H` is to use the `--self-contained` option:

> Produce a standalone HTML file with no external dependencies, using
> data: URIs to incorporate the contents of linked scripts, stylesheets,
> images, and videos.

Then you can do:

```bash
pandoc -f markdown -t html file.md -o file.html --self-contained --css=github-pandoc.css
```

This way, you don't need to create a special `.css` file with style tags. Note that `-s` is no longer necessary as `--self-contained` implies `-s` (although it doesn't hurt).

Please note that this will attempt to include any other assets necessary to display the page (downloading them from the net if necessary!) - check the pandoc documentation of `--self-contained` for details.

Comment: good find, I spent a couple of hours looking for this last year but didn't find this option for some reason ...

Comment: `--self-contained` seems to be deprecated. The flags are now `--embed-resources --standalone`

Answer (score 7):

The way I've done it is to make use of the `-H` option to include a file in the html header. This means you need to wrap your css file with `<style> </style>` tags (so it's not really a css file anymore in the strictest sense). Output gets created like this:

```
pandoc -f markdown -t html file.md -o file.html -H style.css -s
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution I happened to come across since posting this question is the [Juice npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/juice), which also provides a CLI.

It provides the ability to place CSS inline, using a style sheet, with a script like this:

`juice --css style.css original.html final.html`