# Pandoc Markdown to HTML: how to increase margin of list items?

Tags: css, pandoc

I am currently using the following setting to convert Markdown to HTML:

```
-s -t html5
```

This renders list items too narrow for me and I would like to increase the margin between the list items.

Is there any way to do so?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to achieve this is to add additional CSS to the output HTML.

1. Create `style.html` file with the following content.

   ```html
   <style>
     li:not(:last-child) { margin-bottom: 50px; }
   </style>
   ```
2. Add `-H style.html` to include the file in the HTML header part. For example:

   ```
   $ pandoc main.md -t html5 -o main.html -H style.html
   ```

Note that there are many other ways to include additional CSS to the output HTML file (for example you may simply put the `<style>` tag inside your markdown file). Check out this question for more info: [Inline CSS with Pandoc](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54816884/12122460)

Comment: Good answer. The CSS could also use the `li + li` selector with `margin-top`, but that's mostly a matter of taste.

Answer (score 0):

Pandoc distinguishes between "tight" and "loose" lists in Markdown:

```markdown
This list is "tight":

- one
- two

This list is "loose" (note the extra blank line):

- one

- two
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57943159/2425163) for a method to switch from loose to tight lists; replace `Plain` with `Para` (and *vice versa*) in the given code to go from tight to loose.